# How to check if a value in a text value exits in a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a 2D array that looks like this:

```
[['A.J. Greer', 'COL', 'LW', '15', '1', '1', '2', '14', '9', '20', '5'],
 ['Aaron Ekblad', 'FLA', 'D', '82', '13', '24', '37', '47', '180', '114', '88'],
 ['Adam Clendening', 'CLS', 'D', '4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1', '3'],
 ['Adam Cracknell', 'FA', 'C', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '6', '0'],
 ['Adam Erne', 'DET', 'LW', '65', '7', '13', '20', '40', '70', '159', '26'],
 ['Adam Gaudette', 'VAN', 'C', '56', '5', '7', '12', '18', '55', '48', '15'],
 ['Adam Henrique', 'ANH', 'C', '82', '18', '24', '42', '24', '122', '78', '71'],
 ['Adam Johnson', 'PIT', 'C', '6', '0', '2', '2', '0', '3', '11', '3'],
 ['Adam Larsson', 'EDM', 'D', '82', '3', '17', '20', '44', '117', '256', '128'],
 ['Adam Lowry', 'WPG', 'LW', '78', '12', '11', '23', '33', '105', '223', '49'],
 ['Adam McQuaid', 'FA', 'D', '50', '3', '4', '7', '42', '28', '122', '88'],
 ['Adam Pelech', 'NYI', 'D', '78', '5', '16', '21', '24', '110', '149', '116'],
 ['Adrian Kempe', 'LA', 'C', '81', '12', '16', '28', '50', '118', '86', '21'],
 ['Alan Quine', 'CGY', 'C', '13', '3', '2', '5', '6', '11', '14', '2'],
 ['Alec Martinez', 'LA', 'D', '60', '4', '14', '18', '8', '78', '78', '135'],
 ['Aleksander Barkov', 'FLA', 'C', '82', '35', '61', '96', '8', '206', '28', '61'],
 ['Alex Biega', 'VAN', 'D', '41', '2', '14', '16', '22', '91', '101', '43'],
 ['Alex Chiasson', 'EDM', 'RW', '73', '22', '16', '38', '32', '123', '85', '31']]
```

It's a list of players and there stats, I also have a text file that looks like this:

```
Name                    Team  Pos   Games G     A     Pts   PIM   SOG   Hits  BS
================================================================================
A.J. Greer              COL   LW    15    1     1     2     14    9     20    5   
Aaron Ekblad            FLA   D     82    13    24    37    47    180   114   88  
Adam Clendening         CLS   D     4     0     0     0     0     3     1     3   
Adam Cracknell          FA    C     2     0     0     0     0     3     6     0   
Adam Erne               DET   LW    65    7     13    20    40    70    159   26  
Adam Gaudette           VAN   C     56    5     7     12    18    55    48    15  
Adam Henrique           ANH   C     82    18    24    42    24    122   78    71  
Adam Johnson            PIT   C     6     0     2     2     0     3     11    3
```

I want to check if a player in my text file exits in my 2D list and if he does aI want to add all there point totals. This is what I did so far:

```
sum = 0
f = open(filename, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for names in lines:
    if names == stat_list[0]:
        sum += stat_list[6]
return sum
```

However I keep getting zero, any thoughts?

I tried doing this to check each line in my text file and to only check the names in the beginning but it still gives me 0.

```
    sum = 0
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    while True:
        for names in lines:
            if names[20] == stat_list[0]:
                sum += stat_list[6]
        return sum
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Stack Overflow is for specific technical issues, it is not a free debugging service.

Comment: Yeah,  I'm aware of that. I just want to know where I went wrong and I've been stuck on this problem all night.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try debugging or adding a bunch of println statements - your code is probably doing exactly what you tell it to.

I would guess the problem would be in this line:
    if names == stat_list[0]:

You haven't given us what stat_list is, but it might be comparing the name ('A.J. Greer) to the entire first line of the 2d array (stat_list).  This would always be false, and thus sum would never changed.

You might want to add a counter like so:

```
sum = 0
f = open(filename, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
index = 0
for names in lines:
    if names == stat_list[index][0]:
        sum += stat_list[6]
    index += 1
return sum
```

Comment: Hi, stat_list is the 2D array and filename is the file. I tried debugging my code but it's still won't work. I think my issue is with how i'm checking if the two names match. Anything you might suggest?

Comment: Right before comparing the names, add a couple print statements printing the values out.  What do you see?